# Swrast cannot be loaded in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I updated the system today and now I am running into problems while running `optirun glxgears` in a machine with a Nvidia MX150.

I could find several questions regarding similar problems online, however none had solution. So here is my attempt.

At the moment the system cannot run any processes into the discrete videio card.

Here is the minimal example:

```
optirun glxgears
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

- How can I fix this issue in latest Ubuntu?